# What will filter return if all the elements are filtered out ??

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

```
var falsy = [false , null , 0, "", NaN , undefined  ];

return arr.filter(function(element){ return falsy.indexOf(element) ===  -1   ;});
```

why this is returning NaN. Shouldn't it return an empty array  ???

Comment: Best to show what `arr` has prior to the call, but I assume it has at least one `NaN` in it. Also note that the above doesn't return `NaN`, it returns an array with `NaN` in it (as many of them as the original array has).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values

Comment: @T.J.Crowder   yes initially  the arr contains a NaN as one of  the  element. Anyway, Thanks for your response. I have got my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filter` does indeed return an empty array if none of the entries matches the criterion. But `NaN` is never equal to itself, so `indexOf` won't find it (as it compares for `===` equality), so `indexOf` will return -1 for `NaN` even though `NaN` is in `falsy`. So if you have `arr` with `NaN` entries, that code won't filter them out.

`NaN` is a very special value:

```
console.log(NaN == NaN); // false
console.log(NaN != NaN); // true
console.log(NaN === NaN); // false
console.log(NaN !== NaN); // true
```

This is part of why the ES2015 `Map` and `Set` objects don't use `===` or `==` comparisons, but instead the [`SameValueZero`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-samevaluezero) abstract operation, and why the proposed ~ES2016 feature [`Array#includes`](https://github.com/tc39/Array.prototype.includes/) is proposed to use `SameValueZero`. (The spec also defines [`SameValue`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-samevalue), which does the ame thing with NaN but treats `+0` and `-0` differently.)

Once `Array#includes` is in the language, you could use:

```
return arr.filter(function(element) { return falsy.includes(element); });
```

or of course

```
return arr.filter(element => falsy.includes(element));
```

...and `NaN` would be filtered out along with the other falsey values.